# Реализация моб.приложений с помощью html/js/css

Tags: android, мобильные-приложения

Не давно услышал, что многие, сложные страницы(с хорошим дизайном) нельзя реализовать на Java, но зато можно на html/css/js. Это правда?

Comment: не правда. можно все. просто для разных задач есть разные инструменты. одни задачи проще реализовать на java, другие проще на js&html5. вот если возникают проблемы, порой непреодолимые сменить инструмент уже непросто.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На Java можно реализовать "мозги" приложения, логику. Конечный пользователь ее, грубо говоря, не видит, он как раз видит html-документ, с наворотами в виде js и css. И не важно это веб-приложение обычное, или заточенное под мобильные девайсы.

Comment: @masterMind, а как например сделать нормальный скролл. На JS, это е надо специальный библиотеки подключать

Comment: Ну можно конечно и свои писать :) Но обычно да, используют уже готовые библиотеки для создания ЮИ, например jQuery - http://jqueryui.com/demos/ или Yahoo UI - http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/examples/